# Error in inserting data into an array using Mongoose and Node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var FoodSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,

 comments: [{
     text: String

 }]
 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Food', FoodSchema);
```

How do I post values in the comments, I have tried this

```
 router.route('/food')


.post(function(req, res) {

    var food = new Food();      
    food.title = req.body.title;  
    food.comments.text= req.body.comments[0].text;

    food.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Successful'});
    });

    }) ;
```

Title gets inserted, but not the comments

[Postman snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk4yg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [`Mongoose subdoc`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), please try to insert subdocs through `.push` as below

```
food.comments.push({text: req.body.comments[0].text});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
"comments" :[{"text" : "comment1", "text" : "comment2"}]
```

Comment: How do I access "comment2"? isn't it comments[1].text ??

Answer (score 0):

From the client side (request), pass comments like this: `{"comments": [{"text": "Comment 1"}, {"text": "Comment 2"}, {"text": "Comment 3"}]}`.

And in your code you can save it like this: `food.comments` = `req.body.comments`.